# jQuery function for each element

Tags: jquery

I have a function I have just created, but need it to work for each ".headerRHS_2016 #nav_full li a" on the page and not just the first one.

jQuery function Code is

```
function paddSubNavTriangle () {
    var parentLI = $('.headerRHS_2016 #nav_full li a').width();
    var parentLIPaddingLeft = $('.headerRHS_2016 #nav_full li a').innerWidth() - $('.headerRHS_2016 #nav_full li a').width();

    var valuetoPadLeft = (parentLI / 2) + (parentLIPaddingLeft - 11);

    $('.subnavTriangle').css('margin-left' , valuetoPadLeft +'px');

}
```

So currently, this code works to make each `.headerRHS_2016 #nav_full li > .subavTriangle get a` new passed margin-left value - but they all get the same value. That worked out by the sizes of the 1st listed `.headerRHS_2016 #nav_full li a`. How can I adapt this to make this function work for each `.headerRHS_2016 #nav_full li a` element, and therefore get the correct `margin-left` values for each `.headerRHS_2016 #nav_full li a` ?

HTML code is

```
<div class="headerRHS_2016">
<ul id="nav_full" >

<li class="first"><a href="#" title="Link 1" >Link 1</a>
<ul>
<div class="subnavTriangle"></div>
<div class="subnavWrapper2016">
<div class="subnavWrapperInner2016">
<li class="first"><a href="#" title="SubLink 1" ><div class="Sub1"></div><span>SubLink 1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="SubLink 1" ><div class="Sub2"></div><span>SubLink 2</span></a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="#" title="SubLink 3" ><div class="Sub3"></div><span>SubLink 3</span></a></li>
</div>
</div>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#" title="Link 2" >Link 2</a>
<ul>
<div class="subnavTriangle"></div>
<div class="subnavWrapper2016">
<div class="subnavWrapperInner2016">
<li class="first"><a href="#" title="SubLink 1" ><div class="Sub1"></div><span>SubLink 1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="SubLink 1" ><div class="Sub2"></div><span>SubLink 2</span></a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="#" title="SubLink 3" ><div class="Sub3"></div><span>SubLink 3</span></a></li>
</div>
</div>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#" title="Link 3" >Link 3</a>
<ul>
<div class="subnavTriangle"></div>
<div class="subnavWrapper2016">
<div class="subnavWrapperInner2016">
<li class="first"><a href="#" title="SubLink 1" ><div class="Sub1"></div><span>SubLink 1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="SubLink 1" ><div class="Sub2"></div><span>SubLink 2</span></a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="#" title="SubLink 3" ><div class="Sub3"></div><span>SubLink 3</span></a></li>
</div>
</div>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#" title="Link 4" >Link 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="Link 5" >Link 5</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="#" title="Link 6" >Link 6</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your html code please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
function paddSubNavTriangle () {

    $('.headerRHS_2016 #nav_full li a').each(function () {
        var parentLI = $(this).width();
        var parentLIPaddingLeft = $(this).innerWidth() - parentLI;
        var valuetoPadLeft = (parentLI / 2) + (parentLIPaddingLeft - 11);
        $(this).parent().find('.subnavTriangle').css('margin-left' , valuetoPadLeft +'px');
    });

}
```

Basically, I use `$().each` to iterate over all `.headerRHS_2016 #nav_full li a` and I use `$(this).parent().find('.subnavTriangle')` to find the corresponding `.subnavTriangle`.

Comment: Have added my HTML to question

Comment: @dubbs This should work with your HTML, but since you have multiple `a` tags inside different `li` tags, I don't know which one you are targeting with `'.headerRHS_2016 #nav_full li a'` so I am assuming your target outer most (`Link 1`, `Link 2`, ...). If this is not the case, please edit your question.

Comment: Thanks - your code nearly worked, I have tweaked it to get it working. function paddSubNavTriangle () {

    $('.headerRHS_2016 #nav_full li a').each(function () {
        var parentLI = $(this).width();
        var parentLIPaddingLeft = $(this).innerWidth() - parentLI;
        var valuetoPadLeft = (parentLI / 2) + (parentLIPaddingLeft - 11);
        $(this).parent().find('.subnavTriangle').css('margin-left' , valuetoPadLeft +'px');
    });

}

Answer (score 0):

```
function paddSubNavTriangle () {    
    $.each('.headerRHS_2016 #nav_full li a', function( index, value ) {
      var parentLI = $(this).width();
      var parentLIPaddingLeft = $(this).innerWidth() - $(this).width();

      var valuetoPadLeft = (parentLI / 2) + (parentLIPaddingLeft - 11);

      $('.subnavTriangle').css('margin-left' , valuetoPadLeft +'px');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery you could try something like this:

```
var links = document.getElementById('nav_full').getElementsByTagName('a');
Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(link) {
  //do something with the links
  //or call function ...
  console.log(link);
});
```

plunker for that: https://plnkr.co/edit/J5swr9BsQmqbKkLAj5uq